# Processing Js remote pde URL

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, processing

My question is regarding processing js and loading in a pde from a remote URL rather than a relatively one.

My current code base looks like so (with the extra bits omitted for brevity):

```
<script src="pde/mousechaser.pde"></script>
<canvas data-processing-sources="pde/mousechaser.pde"></canvas>
```

The pde file itself can be loaded in from a remote location, but the canvas tag doesn't appear to support remote URLs like so:

```
<script src="http://www.myserver.com/games/pde/mousechaser.pde"></script>
<canvas data-processing-sources="http://www.myserver.com/games/pde/mousechaser.pde"></canvas>
```

Is there a way to use a remote URL in the attribute of the canvas?

Comment: What happens when you use the remote url? Do you get an error? (Check your JavaScript console.)

Comment: @KevinWorkman when a remote URL is used, an HTTP OPTION request is made. I'm guessing this is a preflight request for the file. ProcessingJs doesn't make a follow up request however.

Comment: Is that your actual html? Shouldn't the script src be a processing.js JavaScript file?

Comment: @KevinWorkman yes, this is the actual html. If you refer to the processingJs docs, the script type is "application/x-processing" but this non longer required for html5. In either case, the HTTP OPTION request was the clue - the required headers were missing from the pre-flighted response in order to perform a cross-origin request.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your script look like:

```
<script src="processing.js"></script>
```

Your script tag should reference the processing.js file and not your pde.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="*processing.js file*"></script>
<canvas data-processing-sources="your code.pde"></canvas>
```

You had `your code.pde` in both the script `src` and canvas `data-processing-sources`